# Filter library with vision graph

Tags: document-library, visio, connection

I am working with SP 2013 and Vision 2013. What I like to achieve is to have a connection between a Visio graph and a SharePoint Library. So far I managed to create such a connection but what is missing is that if a user clicks on a shape the library only displays documents that reveal a certain Filter and View.

Hope you understand my problem and can help me out.

Thanks a lot for your help.

PS.: Visio graphs can be displayed through the Visio Web Access webpart

Addition to my first post: 
Visio as the function to add Data to a Shape. 
For example: Customer: Customer 1

Afterwards you setup a connection between the Visio Web Access and the library.
It the settings of the Visio Web Access webpart you have to fill in the field
"Expose the following shape data items to web part connections:" Customer

With this setup it's possible to filter the library by clicking in the shape.
-> Only documents with Customer 1 will be displayed

But the Problem is that you can't attach more the one Value to the Shape.
-> It's not possible to filter more then one value

Comment: Not sure I understood, please review my answer, if it's nowhere near of actual issue, please try to update your question to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You can get to specific Filter and View in SharePoint by defining them in URL, so if you first go to SharePoint, configure the view & filter however you wish, then take the URL from the address bar and use that in Visio Diagram as destination URL.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. That is one possibility as a workaround but the problem with this solution is that all links will open in an new tab. 

I like to have something like in the following tutorial:
http://www.hamishking.com/filtering-lists-based-on-shape-selection-using-visio-web-access/

But with an library connection